# Accelerated Scroll on Recycle View

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, scrollbar, android-recyclerview

I have a RecycleView that have a list of CardsViews. The RecycleView is in a NestedScrollView, because i have a collapsible header. **The scroll isnt accelerated, it stop scrolling when i take the finger from the screen, and i want accelerated scrolling.**

These are my layouts.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".articles.ArticlesActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_articles"
    >


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/articles_lista"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fadeScrollbars="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        />

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

My CardView layout container.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/articles_card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="5dp"

    android:overScrollMode="always"
    android:fadeScrollbars="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/article_card_title"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#000"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

And the JAVA code:

```
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.articles_lista);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        ArticlesAdapter adapter = new ArticlesAdapter(Mock.getNoticias(1L), this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

My new layout is working and looks like:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="newser.sab.com.newser.articles.ArticlesActivity2"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_articles2">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/articles_lista"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fadeScrollbars="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I have exactly same problem, any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Is working changing the layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="newser.sab.com.newser.articles.ArticlesActivity2"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_articles2">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/articles_lista"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fadeScrollbars="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you set your `RecyclerView` inside the `ScrollView`.
So To enable its scrolling faster add this line in your **xml** file in `RecyclerView` Tag

```
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
```

or to do it dynamically add this line in your Java file

```
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```